# mvvmcross showviewmodel byte[] as param

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I work with iOS throw Xamarin. I want's send byte[] from one viewModel to another using showviewmodel.

I invoke this Command:

```
    private MvxCommand _editUser;
    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand EditUser
    {
        get{
            return new MvxCommand
                (() => ShowViewModel<UserViewModel> (new {array = new byte[3]}));
        }
    }
```

and wait my byte[] as param in Init method on another viewModel(UserViewModel):

```
    public void Init(byte[] array)
    {
    }
```

Constructor works good, but then does not reach the the Init method;
It throws an exception:
Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type AccountApp.Core.iOS.UserViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check MvxTrace for more information.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only strings, ints, doubles and bools are allowed in this constructor parameter passing at present.  You would need to serialize this byte[] array to a string and then reconstruct it in the constructor of the view model you are navigating to.